# Присвоение указателя на int

Tags: c

У меня есть такой код. Мне приходиться делать это в две инструкции. Можно это сделать в одну инструкцию?

```
int eax;
char *ah;
ah = (char *) &eax;
ah++;
```

Comment: Что именно "это"? Объявление и инициализацию? Можно.

Comment: А если речь про инкремент, то это просто +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё можно, почему нет?

```
  int eax = (65 << 8) + 66; // A B

  char* c = (char *)&eax + 1;
  printf("%c\n", *c); // A

  c = (char *)&eax + 0;
  printf("%c\n", *c); // B
```

Comment: А разве eax + 1 это не + int?